# How to include Python 2.x binaries in a installation

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu, debian

One of our projects is working with Python 2.7 code and old libraries written in Python 2.x.

As you know, the support of Python 2.x ends this year. We are planning to re-write all of our entire project, but, meanwhile, we were thinking to include python binaries and the old libraries in our Linux installation. Is it possible? How?

I think that the Windows and Mac installations will work without problems. What do you think?

What is the best way to manage this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Debian buster is still shipped with [python 2.7](https://packages.debian.org/buster/python2.7). No need to install it from any thrid party repository.

Comment: But we use Ubuntu and Fedora too, and i can't find some information about the support of Python 2.7 in the last realeases

Comment: Maybe you should use a different search engine. [Ubuntu 19.04](https://packages.ubuntu.com/disco/python2.7) and [Fedora 31](https://apps.fedoraproject.org/packages/python2) also supports python 2.7.

Comment: A friend told me about snap, appimage and flatpack. What is the best option?

Comment: Please do some research by yourself. I'm willing to help you with specific problems, but I'm not your intern who does all the work for you.